# BT keyboard + mouse simultaneously (tablet)

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, tablet, mouse

I have Acer Iconia B1-A71 and what I want to do is to attach a full-size keyboard and a mouse to it. As far as I know, my tablet does not support OTG, so I am thinking of connecting both devices via bluetooth (it has built-in BT 4.0).

Is there any way to connect two devices to tablet via BT at the same time? I do not have neither a keyboard nor a BT mouse and I do not want to spend my money at things I cannot use later.

Or maybe there is a way to enable OTG in this specific tablet (but I have done a little research about my model and I did not found anything useful)?

Comment: You could consider a bluetooth keyboard that has a trackpad. Like the [Aerb Portable Wireless Bluetooth Keyboard](http://www.amazon.com/Ultrathin-Wireless-Bluetooth-Programmable-Rechargeable/dp/B00EZL1N6U/).

Comment: Thanks, but I want to code in PHP on my device, so separate mouse is the best solution for me.

Comment: Then there is no solution for what you're asking for. USB OTG requires hardware and software compatibility (enabled at kernel level). If you were to find a custom kernel that supports it, it's possible that you could work around the hardware limitation by using [powered USB OTG](http://www.amazon.com/Micro-Cable-Power-Galaxy-Samsung/dp/B00CXAC1ZW/), but then you'd also need a USB hub to connect more than one device at a time (eg. mouse and keyboard) [unless of course they shared the same receiver].